# What is the best way to normalize a data set of scores?

Tags: algorithm, normalization

I have a bunch of elo scores (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) that mostly range between 800-1300 (it is an opened end scale so there is no specific min or max).  Someone's score starts at 1000 and then moves up and down based on performance.  I would like to normalize them so I can display scores as 5.0-10.0 with the following requirements:

- it must reflect the relative scale of all scores. Or put another way, since all scores start at 1000 and move up or down from there, the distance each score has from 1000 should be reflected in the normalization.  For example, if the scores were {950, 975, 1000, 1025} they should normalize to lower numbers than {1050, 1075, 1100, 1125}.
- it must retain the distance between scores. For example, if some of the scores were tightly bunched say {950, 950, 955, 1100} they should normalize to numbers that are close together say {6, 6, 6.1, 9}

Comment: A quick search on wikipedia criticizes the use of normalization scores as skewing data for lower ranked players. [Mathematical Issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system#Mathematical_issues). It my be worthwhile to look a little first before asking this question, as it seems that Elo scores are very common, and I am sure others out there know how to do this and have posted about it.

Comment: ELO is not perfect but I don't think the criticism directly relates to this problem.  It is more related to how scores are calculated after each match since that formula uses a normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you don't know what the actual minimum and maximum values of the input range are (because ELO is an open ended scale).

Once you decide what your min and max values will be, clip and linerarly interpolate.

If you don't know how to do that (which is what I suspect) check the wiki for a formula, and/or take a refresher course in grade school algebra.

Comment: Yes the open ended scale is what makes this a difficult problem. If I had a consistent min and max then it would be very easy to normalize but I don't.

Comment: Maybe you should rethink your design.  If the scores are ELO, just present them as received instead of as 5-10  Problem solved - the numbers are what they are.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not meet my users needs.

Comment: well, representing an infinite range with a finite range, something has to give.  clip or compress - the choice is yours.